# Unity/18.04 remove language selector next to keyboard icon

Tags: unity, keyboard-layout, 18.04

I have just upgraded to Bionic Beaver (18.04) from Xenial and after a dabble in GNOME3 I decided to go back to Unity (I prefer having app indicators and a HUD). My keyboard layout is set to US International with dead keys, and I also installed fcitx with Simple Pinyin Support so I could type Chinese.

I noticed that since the upgrade, a language indicator `en` appears next to the keyboard icon while I'm in a text field and on the US keyboard layout. This makes the icons in the tray jump left and right. Is it possible to just keep the keyboard icon and make the language indicator go away?

Comment: Possibly you configured Fcitx separately, which is not necessary on Unity. Instead you should add the input sources, both XKB and Fcitx, via Text Entry.

Comment: I remember having to do something fcitx-related when I wanted to install pinyin support. But the language indicator hasn't appeared until upgrading to 18.04. Any idea what I could do to "deconfigure" fcitx?

Comment: This is a pure guess, but maybe remove the sources you added there. Simple Pinyin is visible in Text Entry, isn't it?

Comment: Pinyin (Fcitx) is visible in Text Entry, as well as English (intl, ...). I do need both though; removing the sources would stop me from being able to write in Chinese. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, of course. What I meant was that you could open `fcitx-config-gtk3` and remove the items in the list of input methods (and only have them in Text Entry). The thought was that maybe the extra icon disappears then. (But it's still just a guess.)

Comment: I tried, but removing it from `fcitx-config-gtk3` also removes it from text entry so I assume they're in sync.

Answer (score 1):

I logged in to a Unity session, enabled Fcitx, and can confirm the behavior. When using a Fcitx input method (in my case Sunpinyin) I see this:

[image]

and when using the English (US) keyboard layout I see this:

[image]

when in an input area, or else the `us` part disappears.

I suppose the explanation is that there exist icons for Fcitx input methods, but not for XKB keyboard layouts, and then it shows the generic Fcitx icon instead together (sometimes) with the abbreviation. If I recall it correctly, it has been like that for a while, i.e. it's not new in 18.04.

If you don't like that behavior, one option is to switch to IBus, install e.g. `ibus-libpinyin`, relogin, and select *Intelligent Pinyin* in Text Entry.

Comment: Thanks for the help Gunnar. I tried `ibus-libpinyin` but it wouldn't show up so I decided to revert to fcitx (it doesn't bother me enough to switch from the software I'm used to), but now it doesn't work in Sublime Text anymore. While I (hopefully) fix that, another option is to go to Input Method Configuration and hit the keyboard button at the bottom, then choose the whatever input method you normally use as the default keyboard layout. That way the `us` thing always shows. Ugly, but at least it's not jumping. Behaviour definitely not observed in 16.04 but that may have other grounds..

Comment: After messing around a bit more, I do get ibus to start but all the input methods listed have "(fcitx)". I'm thoroughly confused now. Also still not working in Sublime Text. I may just reinstall all of Ubuntu from scratch.

Comment: Update: I ended up removing the tray icon altogether and memorising the shortcuts I need (e.g. switching between traditional and simplified Chinese). The problem with Sublime Text 3 was solved by compiling a custom C library (._.) that restores support. I swear it worked before. Not the desired outcome, but acceptable. Thanks for pointing me in the right directions, Gunnar.

Comment: @bluppfisk: Good to hear that you found a decent way. (As regards switching to IBus, it ought to be straightforward; maybe you missed to change the method in _Language Support_.)